# How to access objects by name iteratively (OName1, OName2, OName3...)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, loops, reference

I have a bunch of fields in a winform (textboxes/checkboxes) that have very similar names with numbers appended to them. For example, AName1, BName1, CName1, then AName2, BName2, CName2, etc. What I want to do is iterate through them all in a forloop, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0, i<4, i++)
{
    ANamei.Text = blah;
    BNamei.Text = blah;
    CNamei.Text = blah;
}
```

Obviously, the i in the code above doesnt work. My question is, how do I access the textbox object given this variable within the loop? Thanks!

Comment: Generally you shouldn't use munged names to find controls this way - are you generating these controls in code? If so you should be saving them in for example a List<Control> or ConcurrentBag<Control>

Answer (score 1):

You could add all the control to an array, then iterate through the array:

```
private readonly Control[] m_Controls;

public MyControl() {
    InitializeComponent();

    m_Controls = new[] {
        AName1, AName2, AName3,
        BName1, BName2, BName3,
    }
}

private void DoStuff(string text) {
    foreach (Control c in m_Controls) {
        c.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you really don't want to have a hardcoded list, and the controls are all part of the control you're running the code on, you can use the Controls collection:

```
private void DoStuff(string text) {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        this.Controls["AName" + i].Text = text;
    }
}
```

However, this will be slow if there's lots of controls on the form, as it does a linear scan through every control on the form until it finds the one with the specified name.

EDIT: for multiple repititions, you can use nested loops:

```
for (string prefix in new[] { "A", "B", "C", ...}) {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        this.Controls[prefix + "Name" + i].Text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little more specific than that, because I am doing something very different to AName, BName, and CName (there's actually ~44 different cases), but there's 5 repetitions of each (the number at the end being the only difference). So I was looking for a quick way to copy the already existing code for the first case and do it again for the other repetitions. Is that possible?

Comment: You're going to have to write some loop code at some point. You can hardcode it, or you can use the name lookup on the controls collection, or reflection (which seems silly considering there's the control name lookup). You can use as many loops, nested or not, to get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

if you have to do it by name for members of this class, you could also do it with reflection, but this maybe a little overkill and also slower that the solution of @thecoop
but heres a little sample, just FYI:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class MyClass
{
    private MyObject _myObject1 = new MyObject();
    private MyObject _myObject2 = new MyObject();
    private MyObject _myObject3 = new MyObject();

    public void Foo()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            // get the member of this type MyClass
            var member = GetType().GetMember("_myObject" + i, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var fieldInfo = (FieldInfo)member[0];
            // get the value of the member info
            var field = fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
            // get the property to set
            var propertyInfo = field.GetType().GetProperty("Text");
            // set the value
            propertyInfo.SetValue(field, "my text", null);
        }

    }
}
```